# rspec Object.new does not invoke initialize correctly

Tags: ruby, rspec, initializer

```
module BusinessMath
  class Cashflows
    include Newton

    attr_accessor :cashflows

    def initialize(cashflows)
      @cashflows = rectify_cashflows(cashflows)
    end

    private

    def rectify_cashflows(cashflows)
      cashflows.sort_by! { |cashflow| cashflow[:date] }

      cashflows.each do |cashflow|
        cashflow[:delta] = 0 if cashflow[:date] == cashflows.first[:date]
        cashflow[:delta] = Date.range_360(cashflows.first[:date], cashflow[:date])
      end

      cashflows
    end
  end
end

# spec
before(:all) do
  @payload = [
    { date: Date.parse('1.1.2018'), amount: -100 },
    { date: Date.parse('1.6.2018'), amount: -50 },
    { date: Date.parse('1.1.2019'), amount: 150 }
   ]
end

describe '.initialize' do
  let(:object) { BusinessMath::Cashflows.new(@payload) }

  it 'sets @cashflows' do
    expect(object.cashflows).to eq(@payload)
  end
end
```

This test is supposed to fail since `rectify_cashflows` sorts the cashflows and adds a `delta` key in each cashflow. The expected and in console working `.cashflow` looks like this:

```
[
  { date: Date.parse('1.1.2018'), amount: -100, delta: 0 },
  { date: Date.parse('1.6.2018'), amount: -50, delta: 180},
  { date: Date.parse('1.1.2019'), amount: 150, delta: 360}
]
```

How could I test it the correct way?

Comment: You are right @Stefan was confused switching between original code and this example :)

Comment: Your example code works just fine. Seems like you have edited out the error.

Comment: Wild guess: a typo in `initialize`?

Comment: @Stefan: then it wouldn't have worked in console. My guess is: spring is hung up and is not reloading the code.

Comment: Could you show your _actual_ code?

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes I can get this right.

Comment: You modify the passed-in hash in `rectify_cashflows`, so `object.cashflows` and `@payload` are the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This test should fail since `rectify_cashflows` sorts them and adds a `delta` key in each cashflow.

Yes. The problem is, your rectify method affects `@payload` from your spec too. Because it's **the very same array** (containing the same hashes). Naturally, an object is equal to itself and your test passes.

A simple fix would be to use copying `sort` instead of in-place `sort!`. Or, better, simply deep-copy the array in the initializer. (deep part is important)

Comment: I will go home for today (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ Thanks everything makes sense now. Sorry for the messy start of the Question.